# VC++ dll code region not updated : VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have copied a dll project and started using it with visual studio 2010. I am facing a strange problem. Any additional code I add inside any of the function is not getting executed. The project is building fine. No errors. But when I use the dll with an application, none of the code which I added gets executed. for example

```
int f1()
{
    printf("a");
}
```

is the old code.

New code

```
int f1()
{
    printf("a");
    printf("b");
}
```

When I call f1() from an app which references the dll, I stil get a printed. b is never printed on screen. I disabled the optimization option. must be missing a setting in vs2010 project. Any pointer?

Comment: Clearly it is loading the old version of the DLL.  In the debugger, use Debug + Windows + Modules to see where it got loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're loading the updated library? This sounds a lot like you've got an older copy of your library somewhere and that's the one loaded all the time. This can get a bit tricky in multi-project solutions building dynamic libraries.

Comment: Yes. I checked the timestamp also. The strange thing is in
int f1()
{
    printf("a");
    printf("b");
}

if i write 
int f1()
{
    printf(" ---- a");
    printf("b");
}

output is ---a

Comment: What happens if you change the text that is printed ("a")?

Comment: The modified text is getting printed.

Comment: Really odd then, you're sure there's nothing causing an early exit, like an accidental return or some exception being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

probably an older dll is loaded. check the Dynamic-Link Library Search Order
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586%28VS.85%29.aspx